# Authentication with Azure AD from React JS app

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, cors, azure-active-directory

I have a front end application developed using React JS. I need to provide authentication for this application using Azure AD. I have a requirement of not redirecting to microsoft's login page while logging in. To acheive the same I have created a custom login page as part of my front end application. And on click of Login I am calling azure AD token endpoint using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow and thus I am passing username and password entered into my custom page for authentication. But when trying to call the post method to token endpoint I am getting an error as

```
Failed to load https://login.windows.net/<tenant id>/oauth2/token: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header also but got the same error.

Please help me in fixing the same.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call the token endpoint from a client-side JavaScript app.
The main way of acquiring tokens is to use Implicit Grant flow (get tokens from the authorization endpoint after user has logged in).
You must use the Microsoft login page, you cannot make your own.

You can use [react-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal) to implement the login flow, here is an article on its use: https://itnext.io/a-memo-on-how-to-implement-azure-ad-authentication-using-react-and-net-core-2-0-3fe9bfdf9f36

Comment: I have a backend azure function which does the server side tasks of my client application. What if I move the code of authentication and acquiring token using  Resource Owner Password Credentials flow to this azure function and call function api from my client application? Is this approach right as we have to strictly use our own custom UI?

Comment: Well, that is certainly possible though I still wouldn't recommend it. Are you aware that the ROPC flow will not work for users with MFA for instance?

Comment: Alright. So what is the best option to authenticate against Azure AD by using custom UI and bot redirecting to Microsoft login page from a client side application?

Comment: I don't have experience of making bots with authentication sadly :( The typical pattern with front-end apps is to use implicit grant flow with the library I mentioned in the answer. You won't get a custom UI then. Sadly customization is a bit limited in AAD, and most flows require you to redirect the user to the AAD sign-in page. I haven't received the requirement for a custom UI so far, but I would push back pretty hard on that because of the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: That is convincing. Can you provide a sample for react js app integrated with azure AD?

Comment: Well, there is this one at least: https://itnext.io/a-memo-on-how-to-implement-azure-ad-authentication-using-react-and-net-core-2-0-3fe9bfdf9f36

Comment: I found a property as part of adal.js like 
@property {string} localLoginUrl - Set this to redirect the user to a custom login page
Will this serve my purpose of custom login page?